# Getting Windows download directory path in Robot Framework

Tags: automated-testing, robotframework

I have a Robot Framework test case that makes use of the following variable:

```
${download_dir}    C:\\users\\myProfile\\Downloads
```

How can I change this so that it always points to the `Downloads` folder on any computer? It is assumed that the test cases will only be run on Windows computers.

Comment: This might help https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/master/atest/testdata/standard_libraries/operating_system/path_expansion.robot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To simplify the [link](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/master/atest/testdata/standard_libraries/operating_system/path_expansion.robot) I sent to the comment section:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    OperatingSystem

*** Test Cases ***
Get User Home
    ${user_home}=    Get Environment Variable    UserProfile
    Log To Console    ${user_home}\\Downloads
```

In Windows, there's `UserProfile` environment variable that resolves to e.g. `C:\Users\PavelSaman`, so you can just get its value in RF and append `\Donwloads` to it.